# When will drilling through wall members affect structural integrity?

Tags: doors, drill, studs, structural

When can you freely drill medium to large sized holes in studs or door jambs, and when do you need to be concerned about damaging the structural integrity of the structure?

Comment: please define "medium" & "large" sized holes. And are you talking about timber members?

Comment: There's a big difference between studs that are part of a load-bearing wall (where there is a compressive force on the stud from the structure above) vs a non-load-bearing wall. Answers should take this into account, if the question can't be clarified (since it's worded very generically now).

Comment: @gregmac: I'm thinking in particular of a door jamb, but I was wondering more generally about both cases. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If a plumber does the work, then yes :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found this useful document (direct link to PDF) on the web. It explains in a much clear manner than I can, plus it contains some good, easy to read diagrams.

- [Notching & Boring Guide for Floor Joists & Stud Walls in Conventional Light-Frame Construction](http://www2.wwpa.org/Portals/9/docs/PDF/A11.pdf) by Western Wood Products Association